# Using FFmpeg to detect silence (but not absolute silence) in audio

Tags: ffmpeg

I know that you can use `silencedetect` to get FFmpeg to return the silences in a file, but I want to exclude periods of absolute silence in order to return a silence that has an actual noise profile in order to perform noise reduction.

One way that I think might work is detecting periods of absolute silence, and then excluding those from silence detection in ffmpeg, but I'm not sure how this would work.

Comment: Run silencedetect twice. First, with `n` set to -90dB and then with, say, -50dB. The former will be a subset of the latter. The complement of their intersection is your data. Alternatively, use astats filter with reset=1 and metadata logging enabled. Check for `RMS level dB`.